# How to find the perfect square of a series of numbers in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Good evening, I am having trouble with a classroom assignment(new to java):

```
N is read from the input, and will be an integer in the range 1 to 20. Your program should print out the squares of the numbers from 1 up to and including N, all on a single line, with one space between the numbers. You can use System.out.print() rather than System.out.println() for this.

For example, if 5 is the input, then your output would be:
1 4 9 16 25
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code {
    
  static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    
    // Your code here.
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i+=1) {           
      int s = (i * i);
      List<String>  answer = Arrays.asList(
          
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(s).split(""));    

      System.out.print(answer);
  }
}
}
```

My output:

```
[1][4][9][1, 6][2, 5]
```

How can I format my answer to look like the one in the example?

Comment: probably `for(int i = 1; i <= N; i+=1)  System.out.print(i*i + " ");` ?

Comment: oh yea that works! Thank you so much XD! I prob was overthinking it lol

Answer (score 0):

What about just print them in loop without using List

```java
 for(int i = 1; i <= N; i+=1) {           
      System.out.printf("%d ", i*i);
}
```

or

```java
 for(int i = 1; i <= N; i+=1) {           
      System.out.print(i*i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Code {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();

        // Your code here.
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i += 1) {
            System.out.print( i * i +" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N ^ 2; i^2) {           
  System.out.printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Should be tested...